# I am trying to click this radio button using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Sample code is given below :

```
<input type="radio" checked="" value="0" name="newsRadio">
Yes
<input type="radio" value="1" name="newsRadio">
No
```

Can you please tell me how to proceed,Since name are equal,how to find and click that option using selenium webdriver.

Comment: Below is the sample code<input type="radio" checked="" value="0" name="newsRadio">
Yes
<input type="radio" value="1" name="newsRadio">
No

Comment: @ciaran82 - code is there but OP did not put it within code quote so I have just edited question and will be fine in some minutes. :)

Comment: So only way is Xpath?

Comment: @GopalaKrishnan - check my answer , you can find by xpath or cssselector..

Comment: is that working now?

Comment: Yes..I have used Xpath in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click on radio button **by xpath** using following code :

**For Yes :**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='0']")).click();
```

**For No :**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='1']")).click();
```

**OR**

You can also click on radio button **by Cssselector** using following code :

**For Yes :**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='0']")).click();
```

**For No :**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='1']")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using locator name

```
List<WebElement> radioBtn = driver.findElements(By.name("newsRadio"));
radioBtn.get(0).click //If Yes
radioBtn.get(1).click //If No
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below xpaths

```
//input[contains(Text(),'Yes')]
//input[contains(Text(),'No')]
```